# Dynamic LINQ querying of an ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

Is there any way to use the LINQ dynamic query library (System.Linq.Dynamic) to evaluate a condition based on the properties of an ExpandoObject? The following code throws an exception on the "`var e...`" line, saying "No property or field 'Weight' exists in type ExpandoObject":-

```
const string TestCondition = "MyStateBag.Foo >= 50 && MyStateBag.Bar >= 100";

dynamic myStateBag = new ExpandoObject();
myStateBag.Foo = 70;
myStateBag.Bar = 100;

var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ExpandoObject), "MyStateBag");
var e = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, TestCondition);
var result = e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(myStateBag);
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

The alternative would be to implement the "statebag" as a dictionary, but this will result in a slightly more verbose condition string, e.g. `MyStateBag["Foo"] >= 50 && MyStateBag["Bar"] >= 100`. As this is going to be used as the basis of a user scripting environment, I would prefer the simpler ExpandoObject syntax if it's possible to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. The dynamic LINQ library boils down to an expression-tree, and expression trees do not *directly* support dynamic. Most likely, the dynamic query library is using `Expression.PropertyOrField` to handle `.Foo` etc, and that *will not work* with `dynamic`.

You *could* perhaps write a custom expression parser that replaces this with lots of lookup code if it finds the parameter is a dictionary; not fun, though.

Comment: That's what I suspected, thanks anyway. I might look into NCalc as an alternative...