# Querying a collection of expando objects using Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I have a collection of expando objects / dynamic as

```
var lst = new List<dynamic>();   
dynamic exp1 = new ExpandoObject();
exp1.Name = "ddd";
lst.Add(exp1);
dynamic exp2 = new ExpandoObject();
exp2.Name = "aaa";
lst.Add(exp2);
```

When I am doing

```
var query = from t in lst
where t.Name == "ddd"
select t;
```

But when I am using Dynamic Linq Library

```
var query = lst.AsQueryable().Where("Name==@0", "ddd");
```

I am getting a parse exception from dynamic linq library.

Please help me achieve this.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119264/dynamic-linq-querying-of-an-expandoobject - what you're trying to do isn't supported using the Dynamic LINQ library.

Comment: I am not sure, but I am curious that can it be achieved using a combination of 
ICustomTypeDescriptor
TypeDescriptionProvider and modifying Dynamic LINQ library at necessary places?