# C# Query MongoDb using linq and returning valid Json

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am simply trying to query a MongoDB with Core 5 using Linq.

My collection contains many different document schemas, so I cant make a class to map to.

I ultimately just want to get valid Json output from the query.

Here is what I have:

```
public async Task<object> GetChapters()
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var db = client.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test"); <-- this is a problem as my collection 
                                                                 doesn't have a .Net class to map to

    return await collection.AsQueryable()
        .Where(x => x.ChapterName == "SouthEast Chapter")  <-- of course this fails
        .Select(x => x.Values)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: What is the exact problem that you highlighted in line 5? Is it a compiler-error?

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, but since I have a BsonDocument, I don't know how to do the .where, .orderBy etc.

Comment: I think you can map to a class with the fields you are using in the query filter and select -the fields you want to work with.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have classes for all of the possible schemas. I thought that was the beauty of a documentDB it stores json, any json

Comment: Then, dont use linq - it will work with regular querying and without a class definition.

Comment: You can access `ChapterName` via `BsonDocument`'s indexer. So, Where condition would become: `.Where(x => x["ChapterName"].AsString == "SouthEast Chapter")`

Comment: @ruslan.gilmutdinov The `AsString` errors. But, if the field `ChapterName` is of type string works fine without `AsString`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because LINQ doesn't support dynamic - expando objects.

See [Dynamic LINQ querying of an ExpandoObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119264/dynamic-linq-querying-of-an-expandoobject)

There is plenty of helpers in MongoDB C# driver, below some simple way to query BsonDocument

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver; // Important to have .ToList() extensions
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("mq").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Event3");
    var bsf = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;

    List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>> example1 = new List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>>();
    example1.Add(bsf.Eq("msg", "master"));
    example1.Add(bsf.Eq("to", "server"));
    var result1 = collection.Find(bsf.And(example1)).ToList();

    FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> example2 = bsf.Empty;
    example2 = bsf.And(example2, bsf.Eq("msg", "master"));
    example2 = bsf.And(example2, bsf.Eq("to", "server"));
    var result2 = collection.Find(example2).ToList();

    // To see how to create json syntax from Filter
    Console.WriteLine(example2.Render(BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<BsonDocument>(), BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry));
    string example3 = "{ 'msg' : 'master', 'to' : 'server' }";
    var result3 = await collection.Find(BsonDocument.Parse(example3)).ToListAsync();

    dynamic example4 = new ExpandoObject();
    example4.msg = "master"; // Works only for equality
    example4.to = "server";
    var result4 = collection.Find(new BsonDocument(example4)).ToList();
}
```